# Exclude attribute from a specific xml element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in xslt. I have the following problem. I need within an xml, to remove a specific attribute (`theAttribute`in the example) from a specific element (e.g. `div`).
i.e.

```
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
      <div id="qaz" theAtribute="44">
      </div>
      <div id ="ddd" theAtribute="4">
         <div id= "ggg" theAtribute="9">
         </div>
      </div>
      <font theAttribute="foo" />
   </body>
</html>
```

to become

```
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
      <div id="qaz">
      </div>
      <div id ="ddd">
         <div id= "ggg">
         </div>
      </div>
      <font theAttribute="foo" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Where attribute theAtribute has been removed. I found this, 
http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200404/msg00668.html based on which i made attempts to find the proper solution.

i.e. `<xsl:template match="@theAtribute" />`

Which removed it from the whole document... and others like match, if choose, etc. Nothing worked.. :-( can you please help me on this? it sound trivial to me, but with xslt, i cannot cope at all...

Thank you all in advance

Comment: if you want the code to be formatted, you can highlight the code and click the "010101" button at the top of the edit panel, or indent the text 4 spaces.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What is not working? Do you want the same content, just without the `@theAtribute`?

If so, make sure your stylesheet has the empty template for `@theAtribute`, but also has an identity template that copies everything else into the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->
    <xsl:template match="@theAtribute" />
    <!--identity template copies everything forward by default-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you only want to suppress certain `@theAtribute`, then you can make the match criteria more specific.  For instance, if you only wanted to remove that attribute from the `div` who's `@id="qaz"`, then you could use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="@theAtribute[../@id='qaz']" />
```

or this template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@id='qaz']/@theAtribute" />
```

---

If you want to remove `@theAttribute` from all `div` elements, then change the match expression to:

```
<xsl:template match="div/@theAtribute" />
```

Comment: Hello, these two i had found as well i am afraid but they are not helpful. the first one removes the "theAtribute" from everywhere (divs, body, font, etc tags). 

The second approach removes from everywhere the @theAtribute from all nodes with id=qaz. Is there a way for me to write 
<xsl:template match="@theAtribute[../@nodename='div']" />
??
what i need, is a mix of these two i think, but i cannot figure out the format due to mi ignorance on xslt.

I which to remove the theAtribute from all divs and only from divs.

Comment: I see.  I didn't realize in the description that you specifically wanted to exclude `div/@theAtribute`.  I've updated the answer.  If your XML elements are bound to a namespace, you may need to declare the namespace in your XSLT, or use an XPATH statement that ignores the namespace and matches on the local-name (i.e. `*[local-name()='div']/@theAtribute`)

Comment: For followers, if you want to exclude multiples it can be something like `match="@theAtribute | @otherAttribute"` and they can be full xpath style expressions as well...

Answer (score 15):

inside the select, you can exclude (or include,) the attribute, using the name function.

For example, `<xsl:copy-of select="@*[name(.)!='theAtribute']|node()" />`

Comment: This worked well for me, I wanted to replace one attribute and then copy the rest, and this expression worked well for "the rest"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"  
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

        <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:param name="status"/>

        <!--If attribute is present change it -->
        <xsl:template match="@status" >
            <xsl:attribute name="status" select="$status"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <!-- If attribute is not present add it al last position -->
        <xsl:template match="row[ not( @status ) ]" >
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <!-- put attribute in the last position -->
                <xsl:attribute name="status" select="$status"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <!--identity template copies everything forward by default-->
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have a xml like:

```
<row  attribute1="value" >some stuff</row>
```

and I'm adding at end of list of attributes a status from an outside value.

\saxonee\bin\Transform.exe -xsl:my_script.xsl -s:rows.xml  status="completed"

```
<row current_run="2019-07-29 19:00" status="completed">
```