# awk deleting space for no reason

Tags: shell, awk

**I am using Shell Scripting**

I have the following content in `Config.xml` file

```
<Example>
    <Parameter Name="hello" Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    MO
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="hello" Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="0" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    hiaaa
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="hello" Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    youhoo
    </Parameter>
    <Integer Name="hello" Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="0" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    10
    </Integer>
    <Parameter Name="hello" Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    Receive
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="hello" Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    reporttt
    </Parameter>
    <Integer Name="hello" Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    10
    </Integer>
    <Integer Name="hello" Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
</Example>
```

I run the following shell code to get rid of `Name` attribute

```
awk '{ {if ($2 ~ "^Name*") $2=""}; print $0}' Config.xml > myConfig.xml
```

I do get rid of `Name` attribute BUT I get the following output

```
<Example>
<Parameter  Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    MO
    </Parameter>
<Parameter  Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="0" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    hiaaa
    </Parameter>
<Parameter  Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    youhoo
    </Parameter>
<Integer  Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="0" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    10
    </Integer>
<Parameter  Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    Receive
    </Parameter>
<Parameter  Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    reporttt
    </Parameter>
<Integer  Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    10
    </Integer>
<Integer  Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
</Example>
```

I want the output to be this

```
<Example>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    MO
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="0" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    hiaaa
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    youhoo
    </Parameter>
    <Integer Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="0" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    10
    </Integer>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    Receive
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    reporttt
    </Parameter>
    <Integer Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    10
    </Integer>
    <Integer Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
</Example>
```

Any help??

Comment: Don't use awk to parse xml. Use DOM or XPath

Comment: Your subject is "awk deleting space for no reason", which implies that AWK is deleting a space that you want to keep; but if I understand correctly, the problem is actually that AWK is *not* deleting a space, and you would like it to. Is that correct?

Comment: Please the specific problem you're having. Your question boils down to: *I get this, but I want that. Any help?* That's not a useful question. Don't make us guess what you don't like about the output -- come right on out and tell us.

Comment: @hek2mgl Sorry but I do not have those packages nor do I have the permission to install

Comment: @ruakh No. If you see what I expect and what I get after the execution you will understand. It is deleting extra space and I do not want that.

Comment: @Caleb. True. I did say what I get and what I want. I also put the code I used. What else do you need?

Comment: @Matin: I *did* look at what you expect and what you get. What confused me is that there are some spaces in what you get that aren't in what you expect. I now see that there are *also* some spaces in what you expect that aren't in what you get. As Caleb says, you should be more explicit about what you actually want changed.

Comment: What I "need" is for you to explain what you don't like about the output you're getting. You seem to think that the difference is obvious, but the expected and actual results are quite similar. Furthermore, in comments you say the script is deleting spaces, but the actual result appears to include *more* spaces than the expected result.

Comment: @Caleb Ok. You see how in the result I got `<parameter.....` and `<Integer....` are backspaced. However, in the expected result, they are indented. Is that more clear?

Comment: That helps, but what of the added spaces in the actual result? You have `Parameter__Time` (two spaces) vs. `Parameter_Time` (one space) in the desired result -- this is the point ruakh was making. More to the point, what's so hard about fixing the question to state explicitly what the problem is? Don't explain it in a comment -- edit your question to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` with `gsub` you can remove what you like without adjusting the spacing.

```
awk '$2~/^Name/ {gsub(/ Name="[^"]*"/,x)}1' Config.xml > myConfig.xml
<Example>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    MO
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="0" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    hiaaa
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    youhoo
    </Parameter>
    <Integer Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="0" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    10
    </Integer>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    Receive
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="0" Attribute="hello">
    reporttt
    </Parameter>
    <Integer Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
    10
    </Integer>
    <Integer Time="hello" Time="hello" Conf="1" example="1" Attribute="hello">
</Example>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this answer tomorrow and Accept if correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, `gsub` is not supported on the servers I work with.

Comment: What `awk` version do you have? Try `awk --version`

Comment: Apparently it DOES support gsub im so sorry haha. There's just one thing that I havne't had thought about when I asked this question. I do not know the field number. For example I do not know that `Name` is the `$2`. Maybe it's `$3`. Is there a way to make it check everything?

Comment: Change to `awk '/Name/ {gsub(/ Name="[^"]*"/,x)}1' file` and it will remove fields with name `Name` anywhere in the line.

Comment: Can I please know what's the `1` at the end of the `awk` command? What does it do? And also the regex line you wrote after Name `"[^"]*"/` means what? THankyou

Comment: `1` is always true so it will do the default action, `print $0` So you can write `1 {print $0}`. `"[^"]*"` select all text that is not `"` until it find `"`.  If you write `.*"` it will be greedy and select to much text.

Comment: Oh ok Great. And could I remove XML comments using similar approach? (Without using xmlstarlet or...)

Comment: Give an example on what you like to remove, end I may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your question:

- your xml isn't well formed. You are defining the `Time` attribute twice per element and you didn't closed the last `<Integer>` tag.
- it is no good idea to parse or modify xml with regexes. A stable solution would be to use `XSLT`:

`remove_name.xsl`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->
    <xsl:template match="@Name" />
    <!--identity template copies everything forward by default-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assuming you fixed the errors I named in `config.xml` then you can call now:

```
xsltproc remove.name.xsl config.xml
```

to remove the `Name` attribute.

---

Thanks [@MadsHandsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3117549/171318) for the xsl example.

Comment: thankyou. This XML is just a sample to ask my question. And where I work I do not have access to any additional package nor can I download them

Comment: You might use a programming language like PHP, python, Java, C, ... which might have been pre-installed. All of them have facilities for XSL transformations. If you name an available language I might prefer an example in that language.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But you might call something like `python remove_name_attr.py` from your shell script

Comment: Python isn't supported either :(. It really has to be regex style. I mean I got what I want. I am very close. It's just that I dont know why `<parameter....` and `<Integer....` don't get indented