# Excel XML import creates extra column called NULL for null values

Tags: xml, oracle, vba, excel

I am using Excel 2010 / VBA / XML with the DOMDocument60 parser to produce reports of data in Oracle. I am having a problem with nulls. Oracle supports `null-indicator="yes"` in the xsql query to ensure that null fields are included in the returned recordset. If a field has a value the XML looks like this: `<M_NOTCH>8</M_NOTCH>` and  if it is null it looks like this:  `<M_NOTCH NULL="TRUE"/>`.

My code calls the web service to make the query:

```
Dim XML_HTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Call XML_HTTP.Open("POST", QUERY_URL, False): Call XML_HTTP.send
```

and retrieves the XML results:

```
Dim XML_OUTPUT As DOMDocument60: Set XML_OUTPUT = XML_HTTP.responseXML
```

It saves the file:

```
XML_OUTPUT.Save (FILE_PATH)
```

and then loads the spreadsheet from the saved file:

```
Call DestinationWorksheet.Parent.XmlImport(FILE_PATH, Nothing, True, DestinationWorksheet.Range("A1"))
```

which fills the Excel spreadsheet with the XML data.

If there is a null in the format like `<M_NOTCH NULL="TRUE"/>`, Excel thinks that this is two fields and creates one column for M_NOTCH (with no data for this row) and another column for NULL with a value of TRUE.

I have tried using the xsql setting null-indicator="no", and this eliminates the NULL column, but it has a different, unacceptable problem:  The column order which is built dynamically so that if the first XML record represents an Oracle record with nulls the null fields are excluded from the XML and are only added to the Excel column list when records containing those fields are encountered in which case they are added to the end of the column list.

I have also tried replacing `<M_NOTCH NULL="TRUE"/>` with `<M_NOTCH> </M_NOTCH>` and that was successful.

Does anyone know how to either make Oracle use the syntax `<M_NOTCH> </M_NOTCH>` or get Excel to recognize `<M_NOTCH NULL="TRUE"/>` and not make an extra column?

Comment: I'd be inclined to apply an XSL Transformation to the Oracle response that removed the NULL attribute entirely. The approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3117549/2127508) would achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) (the declarative programming language that re-structures XML files for end use needs) to remove the `@NULL` attribute. VBA can use the XSLT processor with the [Microsoft XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. The needed XSLT is very simple and straightforward where you include the identity transform to copy all content (nodes and attributes) as is and then run an empty template match on `@NULL` to remove attribute wherever it appears in document.

**XSLT** *(embedded below as VBA string)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@NULL">    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA** *(incorporate into your project as subroutine or function, even pass Oracle XML file path as parameter)*

```
Sub TransformXML()

    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    xmlDoc.Load "Original.xml"
    xmlDoc.async = False            

    ' EMBEDDED XSLT ' 
    xslDoc.LoadXML "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
            & "<xsl:stylesheet version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) _
            & "                xmlns:xsl=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "<xsl:strip-space elements=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
            & "<xsl:output method=" & Chr(34) & "xml" & Chr(34) & " indent=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "" _
            & "            encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
            & " <xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "  <xsl:copy>" _
            & "   <xsl:apply-templates select=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
            & "  </xsl:copy>" _
            & " </xsl:template>" _
            & "<xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "@NULL" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "</xsl:template>" _
            & "</xsl:stylesheet>"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "OutputXML.xml"    ' READY FOR FINAL IMPORT '        

    MsgBox "Successfully transformed XML!", vbInformation

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
    Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Set newDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```