# XSLT Remove XMLNS (Name Space) Attribute matching a specific value

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to remove a namespace with a specific value  from all the elements that have it. I am looking for XSLT transformation for it

As shown below , i need to remove **xmlns="NS_647"** from the elements that contain it

Input XML

```
 <COSR xmlns="TEST_NS1" >
    <ORM_O01.PATIENT xmlns="NS_647" >
      <PID>
       <PID.1>1</PID.1>
       </PID>
     </ORM_O01.PATIENT>  
  </COSR>
```

Output

```
<COSR xmlns="TEST_NS1" >
    <ORM_O01.PATIENT >
      <PID>
       <PID.1>1</PID.1>
       </PID>
     </ORM_O01.PATIENT>  
 </COSR>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude attribute from a specific xml element using xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116396/exclude-attribute-from-a-specific-xml-element-using-xslt)

Comment: @Damian No, because "xmlns" is not an attribute.

Comment: Rajendra, can you explain why you want to remove the namespace?

Comment: @Tomalak it is an attribute. From https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/ "A namespace (or more precisely, a namespace binding) is declared using a family of reserved attributes. Such an attribute's name must either be xmlns or begin xmlns:."

Comment: Yes, they are reserved. They cannot be removed with the method you link to.

Comment: @Tomalak yes you are right, they cannot be removed with this method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT operates on a tree of nodes described by the XDM data model, and not on raw lexical XML. In the XDM tree representation of your input, the `xmlns="NS_647"` is not present as an attribute node. Instead, the namespace declaration has two effects:

1. it changes the namespace URI part of the element names within its scope, and
2. it causes all elements within its scope to have a namespace node reflecting the binding of the empty prefix to the URI "NS_647" (incidentally, relative URIs as namespace names are deprecated, but we'll let that pass).

So what you actually want to do in your transformation is to change the relevant elements to be in namespace `"TEST_NS1"` rather than in `"NS_647"`. You can achieve that with the template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='NS_647']">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="TEST_NS1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Michael, the style sheet is not compiling. Can you please check?

Comment: I've fixed it. But it would be more helpful if you gave the error message and line number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have other name spaces in other elements that i dont want to loose.

Comment: So can you edit the question and add the full xml you have