# jaxb-runtime-2.3.0 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a n│ umber: undefined

Tags: java-8, jaxb, xmladapter

While I've seen other very similar questions, I haven't found one that give me a proper solution.

I have XML coming in like this

```
<w id="103" start="0" duration="0" />                                                                                                                                       │
<w id="undefined" start="0" duration="0" />
```

The attribute "id" is defined as

```
  <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:int"/>
```

When the request is unmarshalled it crash with this message

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a number: undefined

   at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseInt(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:125) [jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
```

From other post I would need to create a XmlAdapter but I'm not sure on what class and how to put this in my existing code.

What I'd like to do is to simply ignore those line for which the id="undefined" without rejecting the entire request which lead to loosing data.

Comment: Why don't you make the attribute optional (in the schema) if it may be undefined? It should have the same effect: `<xs:attribute name="id" use="optional" type="xs:int"/>`. In JAXB, the field will be just null if not specified in the XML doc and unmarshalling should succeed with the proper schema.

Comment: ... and make sure the id attribute is absent from the XML to mean that it is undefined.

Comment: actually the value found is "undefined" as a string id="undefined". What I need is a way to recognize the string "undefined" and just ignore that whole entity instead of generating a NumberFormatException

Comment: What I mean is to fix the issue at the source. Since using this special "undefined" value is bad XML practice because it violates the XML schema, I recommend the XML-schema-compliant alternative: make sure that whoever is producing the XML in the first place simply does not include any 'id' attribute in the XML, when it is 'undefined'. And modify the schema to mark the attribute as `optional`. This way, no unmarshalling issue anymore, and XML schema validation works fine, and in your Java code, you just have to check if the field is null to know whether it is undefined.

Comment: Thanks @CyrilDangerville, while I agree to fix at the source, and we did, it could take weeks before our customers manage to get all the level or approval to proceed with the update of the application on they machine and labs. During that time they loose data and they are not happy.  Having a workaround from the server side, until all clients have upgraded their installations could allow us to keep our customers happy has they don't loose data. This issue is for a very special scenario which was overlooked by our QA department as it is part of a module that we rarely used til now..

Comment: In this case, not sure an XmlAdapter is appropriate for a temporary workaround. An alternative is to modify the XML - remove the bad stuff - before passing to JAXB. The standard way of transforming XML is to use XSLT. You can find good examples on stackoverflow on how to remove specific attributes from XML (in certain cases) with XSLT, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116396/exclude-attribute-from-a-specific-xml-element-using-xslt). I could help with a more relevant example if XSLT is OK in your case. I understand XSL can be intimidating at first but it's worth the shot.